# Servlet unable to find file

Tags: java, xml

I have a ServiceHandler class and I want to essentially read in a file. In my init() function:

```
    private String languageDataSet = null; // This variable is shared by all HTTP requests for the servlet
    private static long jobNumber = 0; // The number of the task in the async queue

    private File f;

    public void init() throws ServletException {
        ServletContext ctx = getServletContext(); // Get a handle on the application context
        languageDataSet = ctx.getInitParameter("LANGUAGE_DATA_SET"); // Reads the value from the <context-param> in web.xml

        // You can start to build the subject database at this point. The init() method is only ever called once during the life cycle of a servlet
        f = new File(languageDataSet);
    }
```

In a doGet function, I want to display some info on this file:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
   out.print("Language Dataset is located at " + languageDataSet + " and is <b><u>" + f.length() + "</u></b> bytes in size");
}
```

In my web.xml file, I have the context-param as so:

```
  <context-param>
    <param-name>LANGUAGE_DATA_SET</param-name>
    <param-value>wili-2018-Edited.txt</param-value>
  </context-param>
```

I get the following output:

```
Language Dataset is located at wili-2018-Edited.txt and is 0 bytes in size
```

It can't seem to find the file as I have verified there is text in the file, therefore it shouldn't be displaying as 0. Any idea why the file seemingly can't be found? (The file is in the same directory as the web.xml file).

Comment: Where is the file located? Inside the jar/war? If it's inside the application container it needs to be fetched as a classpath resource and not as a filesystem File.

Comment: @Compass I have the file in the same directory as the web.xml - WebContent -> WEB-INF.

Comment: Then it's not a file. It's a resource inside your war file. A file lives on the file system. And relative paths are resolved from the current directory, i.e. the directory from where your server JVM was started. Use https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String- to read this resource using a path as documented in https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResource-java.lang.String-

Comment: If you're using Spring, you can also leverage the resource resolver: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/support/PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.html